# Upgrading PHP from 7.1 to 7.3 / 7.4 on CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos, upgrade

First of all thanks in advance for the answers!

Kind of legacy server running still on CentOS 6

OS:

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

php:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2019 11:22:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

what i have now:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
php71w-xml-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
php71w-pdo-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
php71w-common-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
php71w-mbstring-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
mod_php71w-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
php71w-mysqlnd-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
php71w-cli-7.1.33-1.w6.x86_64
```

`yum list php73` lists a whole bunch of packages, same command for 74 lists nothing.

PHP 7.3 is enough.

I am a bit intimidated as i haven't found a good walkthrough for my version and i am afraid to not damage anything as i have some working apps on the server.

As i understand i have to do a `yum remove php*` then a something like this

```
yum --disablerepo=remi-php7x --enablerepo=remi-php74 install php php-pdo php-fpm php-gd php-mbstring php-mysql php-curl php-mcrypt php-json -y
```

Edit: I have done a yum update after updating centos 6's outdated repo links, all is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Spooled a new vps from a snapshot then ran

```
yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php73 php php-cli
```

This replaced 7.1 with 7.3

```
Installed:
  php.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi                       php-cli.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi
  php-common.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi                php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi
  php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi               php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi
  php-xml.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi

Dependency Installed:
  libargon2.x86_64 0:20161029-7.el6.remi               oniguruma5php.x86_64 0:6.9.6-1.el6.remi
  php-json.x86_64 0:7.3.25-1.el6.remi

Replaced:
  mod_php71w.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6                      php71w-cli.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6
  php71w-common.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6                   php71w-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6
  php71w-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6                  php71w-pdo.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6
  php71w-xml.x86_64 0:7.1.33-1.w6
```

Hope helps anyone running deprecated centos and php

Comment: Don't forget that CentOS 6 is dead and unmaintained. Also that "remi" repository for EL-6 is closed and don't received any update (latest PHP 7.3 is 7.3.31, fixing some security issues)

Comment: Anyone else stumbling around looking for an official guide on how to update php on Centos: Go to Remi's site and click on the 'Wizard' link: https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/